# Get next value (if exist) per key, value in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have got this king of table:

```
id  number
A.    4
A.    7
A.    8
B.    10
C.    1
C.    9
```

AND I need to add to each row the next number per id using sql, like this:

```
id  number. next_number
A.    4        7
A.    7.       8
A.    8       -/8 (null or the same number if its last)
B.    10.     -/10
C.    1        9
C.    9       -/9
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should do what you want:

```
SELECT
  id,
  number,
  LEAD(number) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS next_number
FROM
  `your_table`
```

You get from this table:

[image]

This table:

[image]

Comment: This is not clear for me: the query here takes the rows in the order they are stored (order by id doesn't change anything, but "partition by" requires an "order by" clause). Can you clarify ?

Comment: @HilaD . . . This answers the question you asked here and on the data you provided would return exactly the results you specify.  I would suggest that you accept this answer and ask *another* question if you have further refinements.